# Images deleted after taking taking memory card

Tags: data-recovery, images

i used 2gb memory card for 5 months in my HTC mobile, i have unmounted it and removed it safely to replace it with 16gb. but now when i try to connect the 2bg card to system and copy the images through adapter, they are lost...every other data is there except the Pics which i took using camera. please help me to recover that pics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the other data is there and you have not deleted the pictures, then the pictures must be there in the sdcard, unless someone else deleted them or moved them.

Try inserting the old sdcard into the phone and see if the phone displays your pictures. If it does, connect your phone to PC in camera mode and save all pictures to your PC.

If the phone also does not show the pictures, you can try the Dara recovery as suggested by Mr.Tech

Comment: Did you get your images back?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not overwritten the data in the 2GB memory card, then you can recover the pics using "Recuva" in Windows PC. The software is available for free download online. Install the software, connect the adapter, select the drive through the application's interface and you will be able to recover the pics.

Answer (score 0):

I assume (only assume, not sure) that those pictures are not on your *external memory card* but on your *internal* one (often referred as **SD card**).
If you haven't configured the camera to explicitly use your external SD card, all your pictures are on your phone's internal storage, independently of your external one.

Look at your pictures folder on your internal storage. There is a good chance that you missing pictures are there.

Comment: the camera storage was explicitly set to memory card which i removed.by the way the phone memory doesnt contain any pics

Comment: Well then you may follow Mr. Tech's advice.

Comment: @saikumar Though you might think so, check twice. You might have "2 SD cards" in your device: the external one you're already considering, and an "internal SD card" (also called "emulated"). Sometimes one needs to really take a closer look to see which one is meant by dialogs. You could use a file-manager on your device to verify. Also, opening the "Gallery" app could help: are the pictures still shown there? Then they're most likely stored on the "internal SD card".

Answer (score -1):

If you have to many  pictures they show  blank  so you should  get a picture program that allows you to make stalks of your pictures to  save room and more  can be keep  on the phone that way